# How can I delete orphaned nested entities in the DB after removing them from a List?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am building a backend for an Angular 8 SPA using .Net Core 2.2.
I am managing `Orders` - each order has an `IList<OrderLine>`. 
I want to use the [visitor pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor) to implement a simple `OrdersService` that only has one update method and does not need to know about any business rules.

I have an abstract `OrderUpdateAction`class that holds an `Order`object. The class has an abstract `Do()` method (each implementation of this method holds business logic). `Do()` returns the updated `Order`object.

My `OrdersService` has only one `UpdateOrder(OrderUpdateAction orderUpdate)`method that calls `Do()`and then hands the updated `Order` to a DbContext for storing the changes to the Db.

**Entities**

```
public class Order 
{
   public Guid Id {get; set;}

   public IList<OrderLine> OrderLines {get; set;}

   [more stuff here]
}

public class OrderLine
{
   public Guid Id {get; set;}

   public Guid? OrderId { get; set; }

   public Order Order { get; set; }

   public string Description {get; set;}

   [more stuff here]
}
```

**OrderUpdateActions**

```
public abstract class OrderUpdateAction
{
     public Order Order { get; set; }
     public abstract Order Do();
}

public class DeleteAction : OrderUpdateAction
{

     public Guid OrderLineId { get; set; }

     public override Order Do()
     {

       if (Order.OrderLines.FirstOrDefault(ol => ol.Id == OrderLineId) != null)
       {
           Order.OrderLines.Remove(Order.OrderLines.FirstOrDefault(ol => ol.Id == OrderLineId));
       }

       return Order;
     }
}
```

**OrdersService**

```
public async Task<Order> UpdateOrder(OrderUpdateAction orderUpdate)
{
     var order = orderUpdate.Do();

     _dbContext.Orders.Update(order);

     await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

     [Caching, logging, etc]

     return order;
}
```

This all works just fine, but when an `OrderLine` is removed from the `IList<OrderLine>` of an `Order`, the OrderLine is not removed from the database - EF seems to just remove the 'link' between those entities by setting the `OrderId` in the `OrderLine` null.

I know that can this behaviour can be useful when multiple 'parent' entities reference that OrderLine, but this is not the case here.

Is there a way to tell EF to delete those orphaned OrderLines, or do I have to manually 'clean up' after the update?

Thanks :)

Comment: You remove `OrderLine` or Order ? If you remove OrderLine, why `setting the OrderId in the order line null.`

Comment: I am just removing OrderLines, I am never deleting orders.

Comment: Have you a config in ModelCreating ?

Comment: Is there any reason why your code is so complex to make such trivial operation as removing relation between objects? It can be done much simpler...

Comment: The idea behind this was to implement different OrderUpdateActions. Deleting an OrderLine is just one of those actions. Having the code structured like that allows me to implement new UpdateActions in the future without changing the API endpoints and OrdersService.

Comment: For me having something like `DeleteAction : OrderUpdateAction` makes no sense as `Delete` and `Update` are two totally separated things and I would say it breaks some of the SOLID principles.

Comment: @GoldenAge Maybe my naming is not ideal, I also have a `UpdateAmountAction : OrderUpdateAction`. This implements business rules like: "A certain product can only be ordered n times by a certain company". But they are all just operations on an order object that. So `OrdersService` is responsible for loading and storing the order and each action (operation) is responsible for changing the order and the frontend is responsible for triggering operations (actions).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look at setting the DeleteBehavior on the Entity Configuration. Check out this post for info on your different options: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete

Comment: This was very useful. Thank you! 
How stupid of me to not read the docs properly :D

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have cascade deleting enabled in your `DbContex`, you can add something like

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OrderLine>().HasOne(x =>x.Order).WithMany().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

to the body of `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)`

> OrdersService that only has one update method and does not need to
>   know about any business rules

I think you are messing up the duty of service with the duty of repository. The `CRUD` operations are usually handled by repository and service is the proper place to maintain the business logic of the app. Because you are using the EF Core there is no need to build a repository pattern over it as it is already a repository so you can just add some extension methods to the DbContext for such trivial operations as Create or Update or Delete things. You can have a look at [this](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/is-the-repository-pattern-useful-with-entity-framework-core/) article to check how powerful options the EF Core gives you.

You can also have a look at this [explanation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/218011/how-accurate-is-business-logic-should-be-in-a-service-not-in-a-model)

"In a traditional layered architecture, service is literally synonymous with the business logic layer. It's the layer between UI and Data. Therefore, all business rules go into services. The data layer should only understand basic CRUD operations, and the UI layer should deal only with the mapping of presentation DTOs to and from the business objects."

Comment: Thanks :) So would you have dedicated method's for each of those operations? Like: `RemoveOrderLineFromOrder(Guid orderId, Guid orderLineId)`, `UpdateOrderLineAmountTo(Guid orderLineId, int newAmount)`, etc.

Comment: If you want to just remove the `OrderLine` from `Order` the extension method would be just e.g. `RemoveOrderLine(orderLineId)` as you invoke it directly on the `Order` object, like `var yourOrder = context.Order.Single(x=>x.Id => givenId); yourOrder.RemoveOrderLine(givenOrderLineId);`

Comment: and you can do all these operations in a body of some method in some service.

Comment: Please keep in mind it's quite a modern approach and you can find a lot of people who still prefer using the old school repository pattern

Answer (score 0):

It turns out all I had to do was make the `OrderId` Guid not nullable. By default the removed OrderLines are deleted then.

[Robert Perry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2648798/robert-perry)'s link was helpful: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete